# jQuery onclick selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

$("input[type='button'][onclick^='save']")

and it works in FF but on IE...

There is something wrong with onclick selector part. Is there a way to make cross-browser workaround?

Thanks Pawel

edit:

```
    $("img[src$='scroll.gif']").click(function(){
    var targetOffset = $("input[type='button'][onclick^='save']").offset().top; 
    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400);
});
```

Comment: So you are trying to find a button whose onclick is bound to a method starting with save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom selector (probably very inefficient though):

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  onclick: function(node, index, args, stack) {
    var events = $(node).data('events');
    var fn = args[3];
    if (!events || !events.click) return false;
    for (i in events.click) {
      if (events.click[i].name == fn) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});

$("input[type='button']:onclick('save')")
```

`function.name` does not work in IE though, so you will have to jump through another hook using toString() and regexps. All in all, you are far better off manually maintaing a list of event handler names.

**Edit:** looking at your code snippet, there seems to be no reason at all to search for event handlers. Instead of wildly throwing attribute selectors around, use classes and ids to address your elements in a semantically meaningful way, e.g.

```
 <img id="scroll-icon" src="icons/scroll.gif" />
 <input id="submit-button" type="submit" onclick="save();" />
```

and then

```
$("#scroll-icon".click(function(){
  var targetOffset = $("submit-buttton").offset().top; 
  $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, adding ID is the simplest solution. But as I mentioned above in one comment, I have hundreds of those "scroll image & button to scroll" pairs in project. Don't ask why :)) Anyway, thanks for informative answer. I think I will end up adding ids/class attributes though...

Comment: The traversal functions in jQuery are very flexible. Use classes, and you can probably find the right button based on its relative position in the DOM tree. E.g. `$(this).parents('.block:first').find('.submit-button')` will find the container (with `class="block"`) of the icon, and look for the submit button there.

Comment: Even simpler (you learn something every day): `$(this).closest('.block').find('.submit-button')`

Answer (score 6):

It should be like :

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function(){
//do something
});
```

You should put this in [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function

**EDIT** is this what you want?

```
$('img[src="scroll.gif"]').click(function(){
        var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top; 
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. But I wan't to achieve something else. Check out full code

Comment: @dragonfly what do you want to achieve, can you please edit your question, a bit more details would help

Answer (score 3):

Do you have more than one button that is a save button?  If not, why don't you just assign your button an id?  That makes it a lot simpler, and the id selector, which wraps `document.getElementById()` is very cross-platform.  Then, all you need is `$("#buttonID")`.

EDIT: Given the OP's criteria, I'd suggest a class (just for use as a selector) such as "jumpToSave".  Each button should have that class, and then the selector could use `$(".jumpToSave")`

Comment: I wish I had only one button of that kind. But unfortunately I have hundreds of them in whole project... So I wanted to minimize effort needed.

Comment: Can you give them all the same class and do it that way?

Answer (score 2):

You can't look for a value like that in event attributes. The browser creates a function from the string value in the attribute.

If you have an attribute like this:

```
onclick="save();"
```

The attribute contains a function reference rather than a string. If you read the attribute and get the value as a string, you get the code of the function.

When reading the attribute value in Firefox, this is what you get:

```
function onclick(event) { save(); }
```

When reading the attribute in Internet Explorer, this is what you get:

```
function onclick(){save();}
```

You have to use some other attribute to identify the button.

Comment: I get your point. Even though $(el).attr("onclick") doesn't return string save(), selector provided above worked in FF, that's why I wanted to use it. Thanks for info.